# Sending two video feeds from PowerPoint

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint

Is it technically feasible to send two feeds from PowerPoint?    I need one feed with Normal view sent to our projector, and a second feed with the Presenter View sent to a secondary video monitor.  I would continue seeing the Presenter View on the source computer (in the control booth).

Another way of showing what I need:

```
Source PC   -> Presenter View  (control room)
- Monitor 1 -> Presenter View  (sent to video monitor by the podium)
- Monitor 2 -> Normal View     (sent to projector)
```

As for the hardware I'm pretty sure I'd need two graphics cards do this.  But first I need to know whether it's even possible to do what I'm asking in PowerPoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is doable.  By setting up the projector as an extended desktop, this should be default behaviour:

[image: See Example]

Above is an example of what happened when i fired up my windows 7, Powerpoint 2010 installation and clicked play slideshow "from the beginning" from the slide show menu.

Note: the left screen is my primary display (start menu) and right is my secondary display.  You can change this by using the "Show On" drop down list as seen below:
[image]

Edit: seeing your update to your question - you should be able to use a splitter to set both your control room and monitor 1 as duplicates and monitor 2 as a secondary.